# Multiple error messages upon upgrade to CiviCRM 4.2.20

Tags: upgrade

I am trying to upgrade from 4.1.5 to the latest CiviCRM but need to go through some intermediate releases to get there. I have installed 4.2.20 but get the following error dozens of times on each screen.

> Strict warning: Non-static method CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues()
>   should not be called statically in CRM_Core_Block::setTemplateValues()
>   (line 587 of

Is there any way to get rid of it?

Answer (score 2):

Those are warnings, not errors. It's simply PHP telling you that CiviCRM 4.2 is a rather old piece of software (which it is!). They will not prevent CiviCRM from working normally, certainly not for the brief time between now and when you get it upgraded further.

I recommend you ignore them and proceed with the upgrade. The latest version of CiviCRM is more up-to-date so will not trigger php warnings.

Answer (score 1):

Can you upgrade to a later version than 4.2.20? [Some Googling](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=26411.0) indicates this error may be solved in later versions.

Comment: It was suggested in an answer to another question that I update the 4.1.5 database in 4.2.xx then upgrade to a later release after that.

Comment: Assuming you are on a dev/testing server with a copy of the database, I would now try to upgrade to the next version (despite these Strict warnings).

Comment: Okay. I'll try to update the database now then upgrade.

Comment: Did it work? :)

Comment: update did not work.

Comment: Sorry to hear it. Feel free to update the question above with more info in that case.